# push metrics from node exporters to remote prometheus server

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

We are trying to setup prometheus-grafana solution for monitoring , it worked when exporters were on the same network ,my question here is :

How to push metrics from node exporters in a network to a remote prometheus server in a nother network , is that doable

Answer (score 0):

1. Deploy a Prometheus inside that network, use [remote_write](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#remote_write) to push data to your remote Prometheus.
2. Essentially the same as above but with [Grafana Agent](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana-cloud/agent/). They made it for their own cloud, but they also say you can use it with your own Prometheus. The thing is like a lightweight Prometheus, capable of scraping exporters and pushing data into Prometheus.
3. Create a proxy into the network and use it as a gateway in.

Comment: many thanks for the suggestions I'll try them and reply again